# 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The requested database WebBank is not defined in configuration

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Can please some tell me when does the above written error occurs. I just wanted to get more information on this.

Comment: Please provide more context around this error - it's telling everything you need to know, but probably nothing at the same time.   Do you know what causes that type of exception and why it might be looking for the WebBank database in the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `config` file where you mentioned the `connection string` and correct it...
The database mentioned might not be a valid one, or the server name might not be valid.
Your connection string should look like this

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your connection string to the host library or the start up project.
2. It is clear that you are trying to access the config entry and it is not found thus this error thrown by the Configuration Manager/accessor.
3. Give us some code to diagnose the issue its hard to guess what causing the error.

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to know more about this exception. However, I figured out the error that I was receiving. that is y I just wanted to know the nature of the issue. I have placed my connection string properly in my app.config file but made a little mistake in the code. Thank you for your help.